# Asymptotic Approximation for a Derangement Algorithm

Tags: permutations, asymptotics

**Asymptotic Approximation for a Derangement Algorithm**

I have been analyzing the complexity of a simple algorithm for randomly generating a derangement, i.e., a permutation $\pi$ with no fixed points: $\pi_i \ne i,\, i = 1,2, \ldots,n.$

The expected total work of this (Las Vegas) algorithm is
$$
    W_T(n) = W_s(n) + \frac{1-p(n)}{p(n)}W_f(n),
$$
where $p(n)$ is the probability of success (a derangement is generated), $W_s(n)$ the expected work to generate a success, and $W_f(n)$ is the expected work to generate a failure.

I know that $W_s(n) = n-1$, and $p(n) = 1/e \approx 0.368$, but I'm having difficulty with $W_f(n)$. Here is what I have so far:
$$
    W_f(n) =\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k p_{nk}= \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\,\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n-i}\right).
$$
$W_f(n)=4.4, 49.49, 499.499, 4999.4999, 49999.49999$, for $n = 10^1, 10^2, 10^3,10^4,10^5.$

This suggests that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\,\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n-i}\right) = \frac{1}{2}n.
$$

We now have all the pieces of the first equation equation and we get

$$
    W_T(n) = n-1 + \frac{(1-1/e)}{1/e}\frac{n}{2}  = \frac{\left( e+1\right)}{2}\,n-1 \approx 1.86n .
$$
Testing the algorithm shows that this is roughly correct, but I have not been able to prove the $\frac{1}{2}n$ limit above. The best I have come up with so far is
$$\ln(kp_{nk}) = H_n-H_{n-k},\quad W_f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} e^{H_n-H_{n-k}}$$
which goes to something like $2n-\ln n$. This does not seem correct. Any help would be very appreciated.

Derek O'Connor

Comment: By pure coincidence I came across this post again and realized you made an edit to include another question you need help with. Unfortunately I can't help you right now, but my advice is that you should make a completely new thread on the new question. Barely anyone would be opening this question anymore, its many pages from the front page.

Comment: @Ragib, Thanks for your advice. I have found a flaw in the Matlab function above. A small patch fixes it but I don't like that so I'm going to delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n-i}\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{n-(k-1)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n-1}\cdot\frac{n-3}{n-2}\cdot\cdots\frac{n-(k-1)-1}{n-(k-1)} $$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-k}{1}$$ due to massive cancellation in consecutive numerator/denominators. Hence the sum is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}1\right)-\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k\right)$$ 
$$=(n-2)-\frac{1}{n}\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{n-1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$$

which matches the given calculations exactly. Note the formula for the [triangle numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) above.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it! I had the same answer half typed up =[ lol.

Comment: @Ragib: The moment I saw the pattern I knew this would end up a race to type it out. ;)

Comment: @anon: Superb! Thank you very much. Why didn't I see that?